# How to access multiple IP-s of host from virtualbox guest windows

Tags: windows, ip, virtualbox, host

I have a linux host with virtualhosts on 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2 and 127.0.0.3 (the reason is that I need multiple domains with https) and I would like to access them from virtualbox in a windows guest. Now I know that 10.0.2.2 in the virtualbox gets to 127.0.0.1, but I need to get to the other IP-s of the host in order to enable IE to see my virtualhosts in https. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These IP addresses are loopback addresses. They aren't bound to your network card. To access your host through several IP addresses, you need several network cards, or virtual IPs. But this can't work with `127.0.0.X`

Comment: thanks. I changed the IP-s on the host, added eth0:1 = 192.168.142.1, eth0:2 = 192.168.142.2, eth0:3 = 192.168.142.3, and I use these IP-s from the guest OS (and not 10.0.2.2)